# Cannot remove index.php from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

I've changed `$config['index_page']` to

```
$config['index_page'] = ''
```

and also updated my .htaccess file content to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

but I can't access controllers without putting index.php in my url.
So what should I do next?

Comment: Do you run your server on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @cuewizchris, I'm running on windows

Comment: You need to ensure that your rewrite engine is running and - perhaps - there is a line in your vhost config that you need to change (from "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"). I'm not sure how these steps are supposed to be done on Windows, tho.

Comment: .htaccess is not turned on by default on a windows server. Make sure first this is the case. Take a look at this response and article about configuring it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148489/htaccess-file-on-windows-server

Comment: Have a look in this post ..... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852585/how-to-call-codeigniter-controller-function-without-url-without-index/17852790#17852790

Answer (score 0):

try with following .htaccess, it works fine for me.

```
# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

put this code in your root folder htaccess file and clear your application folder htaccess file's content.

please let me know if you face any problem.